# passing find result to custom script

Tags: ubuntu, grep, find, xargs

I need to pass each filename that return find function to my script
consider simple example:

```
find ./ -iname "*.java"  | xargs ./fnfs2lc.sh
```

and fnfs2lc.sh contains simple code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1 
exit
```

Thus as a result I'm expecting to get list of files however it only shows the first file in the directory tree.

If I execute:

```
find ./ -iname "*.java"
```

result is:

```
./src/test/java/com/win/slots/picktables/SequnetialPickTableTest.java
./src/test/java/com/win/slots/picktables/WeightPickTableTest.java
./src/test/java/com/win/slots/picktables/AccuratePickTableTest.java
./src/test/java/com/win/slots/picktables/RangePickTableTest.java
./src/test/java/com/win/slots/picktables/KeyPickTableTest.java
./src/test/java/com/win/slots/api/WinningAmountTest.java
./src/test/java/com/win/slots/api/BIEventSenderTest.java
./src/test/java/com/win/slots/api/ParserTester.java
./src/test/java/com/win/slots/api/WindowTest.java
```

and if I run first command I get:

```
./src/test/java/com/win/slots/picktables/SequnetialPickTableTest.java
```

Do you know why it stops processing after first file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is using `$1`, so that is the first result in the list. If you want to print all results you could use:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

Also, you do not need `xargs`, you could use

```
find . -iname "*.java" -exec ./fnfs2lc.sh {} +
```

If you use the less efficient

```
find . -iname "*.java" -exec ./fnfs2lc.sh {} \;
```

Then you could use

```
echo "$1"
```

But note the quotes around `$1`